# Object doesn't support this property or method VBA Loop not ending

Tags: vba, excel

Hi all I am very new to the vba scene! I am having trouble with this code. I have been trying to work out what is happening with it... When I press F8 there is no error code coming up but it keeps on looping in the if statements

```
Sub testing()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim xRow As Integer
xRow = 1


With Me
    .Columns(1).ClearContents
    .Cells(1, 1) = "ROLES"
    .Cells(1, 1).Name = "Roles"
End With

For Each ws In Application.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> Me.Name Then
        xRow = xRow + 1
        With ws
            .Range("A1").Name = "Start_" & ws.Index
        End With
    End If
Next
Application.Sceeenupdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Use `F5` instead of `F8` to run through the entire subroutine

Comment: @CodyG It comes up with this error- 'Object doesn't support this property' when I press f5

Comment: Are you sure your code is working. Visually I can see that It will fail on `With Me` and `If ws.Name <> Me.Name Then` and then on `Application.Sceeenupdating = True`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Um when I tried to debug it using f8, it goes past that part fine.

Comment: Learning debugging - which line of code has the issue when you press `F5` ? There are a few ways to do this. I would comment out the `.Range` line. Or I would put a print statement at the `.Range` line with the xRow and ws name

Comment: @SiddharthRout Is there anyway to change it? I am trying to make a list of multiple sheet names in a column.

Comment: ( you should change it to `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` )

Comment: Which sheet do you want the result in?

Comment: @CodyG When I press it there is no line that is highlighted thats why I went to debugging. Am I using debugging wrong?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Just sheet1. I replaced  ws("Sheet1") with me because it wasn't working.

Comment: So you want the names of all the sheets in Col 1 of Sheet1?

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes exactly

Comment: Refresh the page. I posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are you sure your code is working. Visually I can see that It will fail on With Me and If ws.Name <> Me.Name Then and then on Application.Sceeenupdating = True – Siddharth Rout 11 mins ago
>
> So you want the names of all the sheets in Col 1 of Sheet1? – Siddharth Rout 2 mins ago   edit
>
> @SiddharthRout yes exactly – Zoe Chu 13 secs ago

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub testing()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim xRow As Long

    '~~> This is the sheet which will have sheet names
    '~~> in Col 1 ("A")
    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wsMain
        .Columns(1).ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1) = "ROLES"
        .Cells(1, 1).Name = "Roles"

        xRow = 2

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> wsMain.Name Then
                .Cells(xRow, 1).Value = ws.Name
                xRow = xRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hiya, its now highlighting the 'Application.Screenupdating=True' now

Comment: I tested the code before posting :) There is nothing wrong with that line.

Comment: Man.. What am I missing

Comment: Where have you pasted the code? And did you make any changes to my code?

Comment: Thanks again! @SiddharthRout

Answer (score 1):

`Application.Sceeenupdating = True`

should be

`Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

This would be a little more obvious if you set the following option in the VBA editor:

Tools > Options> Set Error Trapping to "Break on All Errors"

[image: error trapping]

Which should then pop up with

[image]

Clicking debug gets you to...

[image]

Comment: Ahh! Okay. I thought I was going crazy when people were talking about a 4 button error message box.